# Changing digits in a number to other digits

Tags: excel

How do I replace all of the 0's in a number with 2's?

**Example**

Input

```
110101000110
```

Output

```
112121222112
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you having problems exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to use substitute. Assuming you have stored the string in the cell A2, write: `=SUBSTITUTE(A2, "0", "2")`. Have a look at the [documentation of the function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/substitute.php).